# Weird PyPI authentication behavior

Tags: python, distribution, distutils, pypi

I'm trying to upload my package to PyPI. It asks me to identify, I do, it gives an OK response (which doesn't happen unless the identification is right), but then it claims I didn't identify! Why?

```
[...]
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
running register
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:  1
Username: coolRR
Password:
Server response (200): OK
running upload
Submitting dist\garlicsim-0.1.zip to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
removing 'build' (and everything under it)
error: garlicsim-0.1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What exact command did you try to run, with all the options you specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using an old version of Python (and Distutils as a result). This bug was fixed in r68415 2009-01-09 by Tarek Ziade. Try to upload with any Python 2.x version released afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered that myself, but some things to check:

1. Make sure you can login to PyPI using your browser with the username and password.
2. Check that ~/.pypirc has the correct contents. If it does not exist, try creating it.
3. Check your setup.cfg file to make sure all the PyPI settings (if any) are correct.
4. Try building your package as separate check before you run the commands to upload/register, then try python setup.py upload.